# Couple of Change set related questions

Tags: sandbox, change-set, tab, migration

While migrating from 1 sandbox to another, I faced the following issue/doubt....

1. For migration, I chosed 2 vf tabs to move to the target sandbox. In the target instance I'm able to see the tabs but they don't appear on the tab location. Only on clicking the "+", I am able to see the 2 tabs. Do I have to manually go to each profile and customize my new tabs?
2. My second problem. So I have developed 2 tabs, 3 custom object, 5 lookups and MD relations on already existing objects(std/custom). So when I add my new custom objects and fields and click on ADD DEPENDENCIES, I'm presented with many other fields, which I haven't even touched. Is it safe to check the ***all check*** checkbox? Also will the ***all check*** checkbox ensure that label changes on a new custom object's field.

I hope I'm clear enough. Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want the tab settings to go through you need to also include the App where the VF tabs were added in the change set.
2. I wouldn't recommend adding all dependencies unless you are the only developer in the org and you are completely sure nothing has changed in all the other components,  I prefer to add each component even if it takes much more time.

Comment: 1. make sure you also include the Profiles you want to have this tab as "Default On".